# Google Chrome extension: Getting all links in page

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make chrome extension, that can recursively go trough the website and search for common error message strings (like "Error 500" etc.), for web developer testing.

The first step is get all links from the active tab. So, in my extension's background script I have this code snippet:

```
var $html = jQuery(html);

var links = [];
$html.find('a').each(function(){
    console.log(this);      
    console.log(this.href);
    //links.push(this.href); 
});
```

But output of this script is weird for relative links:

```
<a href=​"/​" id=​"logo">​</a>​
chrome-extension://kmldadmcjflefibfflbkpmgjdpklghfa/ 

<a href=​"#top">About</a>​
chrome-extension://kmldadmcjflefibfflbkpmgjdpklghfa/background.html#top 

<a href=​"/articles/applications/​1">​Web applications</a>​
chrome-extension://kmldadmcjflefibfflbkpmgjdpklghfa/articles/applications/1
```

Though element's `href` attribute has the value '/', dumped `this.href` outputs 'chrome-extension://kmldadmcjflefibfflbkpmgjdpklghfa/'.

How can I get link's href value without 'chrome-extension://blahblahblah/' ?

Comment: Read the attribute rather than the resolved `href`, by using `$(this).attr('href')` or `this.getAttribute('href')` instead of `this.href`.

Comment: Rob W: Thanks very much! I don't have any idea why `$(this).attr('href')` works and `this.href` not, but it solves my problem :-)

Comment: Because `this.href` is a property which returns the resolved URL, and `.attr` or `.getAttribute` returns the attribute as set on the element.

Answer (score 2):

You are parsing your own extensions background page. Is that really what you want to do?

If your intention is to parse another page, use a "content script".
It is extensively documented here:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Edit after your comment:

So you just want to get rid of "chrome-extension://..."?

```
var str = 'chrome-extension://kmldadmcjflefibfflbkpmgjdpklghfa/background.html#top';
var out = str.replace('chrome-extension://kmldadmcjflefibfflbkpmgjdpklghfa', '');
```

Or better yet, just get both name and URL from your "this".

Comment: No, `html` is really from active tab. It is string, that contains HTML source from active tag. I am sure about that. The code above is only part of my script.

Comment: Ok, your code will return 'background.html#top', but I want to get '#top'. So, I can manualy cut also 'background.html' text, but I think **this is not clean way to do this**.